# Как сделать так чтобы только создатель мог удалять свою запись Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Допустим пользователь сосздал свой коментарий. Как сделать так чтобы только он мог его удалить а не кто-то другой кто знает Id коменатрия?

```
  @DeleteMapping("/updateComment/{commentId}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteComment(@PathVariable("commentId") Comment comment){
        return commentService.deleteComment(comment);
    }
```

Мой Spring Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

@Autowired
public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler){
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
}

@Bean
public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter(){
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/profile/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/posts/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/tags/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/images/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/avatars_min/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/avatars_full/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/posts_images/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/topic/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/socket/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/notify/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте проверку юзера перед удалением. Например как-то так:

```
@DeleteMapping("/updateComment/{commentId}")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteComment(
    @PathVariable("commentId") Comment comment,
    @AuthenticationPrincipal User user
) {
    if (comment.getAuthorId() == user.getId()) {
        return commentService.deleteComment(comment);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Access denied!");
    }
}
```